# Function chaining in TypeScript with Omit types

Tags: typescript, chaining, method-chaining

Let's say I wanted to implement a typed function chain in TypeScript, but in this case, calling a function removes that function from the return type. For example:

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

interface Chainable {
  execute: () => Promise<void>;
}

interface Chain1 extends Chainable {
  chain1?: () => Omit<this, 'chain1'>;
}

interface Chain2 extends Chainable {
  chain2?: () => Omit<this, 'chain2'>;
}

let chain: Chain1 & Chain2 = {
  execute: () => null,
  chain1: () => {
    delete chain.chain1;
    return chain;
  },
  chain2: () => {
    delete chain.chain2;
    return chain;
  }
};

chain.chain1().chain2().execute(); // Using the function chain
```

When I call `chain.chain1()`, I would get `Pick<Chain1 & Chain2, "execute" | "chain2"` as the return type, which is great, since it prevents me from calling `chain1` twice.

However, as soon as I chain it with the `chain2` function, the return type becomes `Pick<Chain1 & Chain2, "chain1" | "execute"`. This would allow me to call `chain1` again, which is what I'm trying to prevent. Ideally, the compiler would complain that `Property 'chain1' does not exist on type`:

```
chain.chain1().chain2().chain1(); // I want this to return a compiler error :(
```

Am I going about this the right way? Is it possible in TypeScript to progressively combine multiple Omit types together, so that the return types continuously omit properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the type for `this` is determined when the function is first checked and then not reevaluated at any point after. So `this` for the second call of `chain2` will still be the original `this` not the return type of `chain1`. I am not sure if this is the intended behavior or a bug, you might want to check GitHub for similar issues.

One workaround is to capture `this` for any given function using a generic type parameter which will be tied to `this`. This will ensure correct type flow through the function chain. One small issue is that the typings will not work out using arrow function, you will need to use regular functions and access `this`:

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

interface Chainable {
    execute: () => Promise<void>;
}

interface Chain1 extends Chainable {
    chain1?: <T extends Chain1>(this: T) => Omit<T, 'chain1'>;
}

interface Chain2 extends Chainable {
    chain2?: <T extends Chain2>(this: T) => Omit<T, 'chain2'>;
}

let chain: Chain1 & Chain2 = {
    execute: () => null,
    chain1: function () {
        delete this.chain1;
        return this;
    },
    chain2: function ()  {
        delete this.chain2;
        return this;
    }
};

chain.chain1().chain2().execute(); // Using the function chain
chain.chain1().chain2().chain1().execute(); // error
```

Comment: Good idea with the `this` parameter.

Comment: @jcalz 10x, I am now having doubts about who `this` is. I would have expected his code to work, I guess polymorphic `this` is determined when the function is declared and not re-evaluated after.

Comment: This is perfect! I fiddled with having an input parameter of `this`, but I didn't think of using generics to extend the class. Thank you!

Comment: This breaks down when you have user-supplied generic arguments, since the caller now has to provide the type of T for each call.